# Update the value of a specific field in solr

Tags: solr, solr8

I am trying to update the value of existing field in solr document to a new value using curl.Below is the query and response. But I do not see the value for code getting reflected in solr. Please help to resolve the issue.

```
curl  -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8390/solr/collection/update' -d '[{"id" : “12345”,”code” : {"set" : “500”}}]’
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "rf":1,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":11}}
```

Comment: are you committing after the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have missed the `commit=true` in your request and hence the issue.

Try the below command and hopefully it should work for you.

```
curl  -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8390/solr/collection/update?commit=true' -d '[{"id" : “12345”,”code” : {"set" : “500”}}]’
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "rf":1,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":11}}
```

Comment: Thanks Abhijit. Commit was the issue.

Comment: I am facing one more issue here. The updated record has other fields like name,place etc..If I search with name in the query parameter (q), record is not showing up.But if I include name as fq parameter, I am able to see the record. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you create another question with more details like what are exact fields with some dummy data. ANd what is the query been fired